# Can't get an image asset

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Why i can't get an image to work. I'm trying this:

```
background-image: url(jBootstrap/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
```

and it doesn't work. When i'm trying to access it trought URL i get an error:

> Asset [stylesheets/jBootstrap/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png] was unable to be processed.

Can't get any images, tried in many variations of directories and still doesn't work. When i'm doing this on plain html-css it works perfectly, but not in laravel. What am I doing wrong ?

btw, i'm using Basset if it helps.

#### EDIT 1

Also including the additional information about a partial structure of my public folder and html link generated by basset:

- public/

  - stylesheets/

    - jBootstrap/

      - images/

        - ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
    - main.css `it contains the background-image...`

when including the css file, in source code i see:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Job/worker/myapp/public/7n3C5wypAmTi8VT8/application/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

#### Edit 2

Adding my public/.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Edit 3

Tried another way:
`public/stylesheets/main.css`
`public/stylesheets/abc.jpg`
in `main.css` I have code: `body { background-image: url('abc.jpg') }` and i'm getting nothing ...

Please help, struggling 2 days now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem... It was Basset package, it wat required to put `$collection->apply('UriRewriteFilter');` into configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I would naturally assume that one (or both) things are incorrect here:

1. Your `.htaccess` file is not checking for existing files when rewriting. Check to see if `RewriteCond {%REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` exists in that file.
2. You are not requesting your background image from the root, i.e. absolutely. Try requesting the resource using a leading slash. For example, instead of calling `foo.png`, try calling `/foo.png`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setArguments('../')` on your collection

```
'collections' => array(

        'application' => function($collection) {
            $collection->add('../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less')->apply('Less');

            $directory = $collection->directory('assets/stylesheets', function($collection) {
                $collection->add('main.css');
            })->apply('UriRewriteFilter')->setArguments('../')->apply('CssMin');
        }
 ),
```

This did the trick for me.